# Merge many Excel columns with a keyboard shortcut or button (if possible, without a new column and formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

**How to merge multiple string columns into a single column, with a separator (for example `;`), with Excel?**

If possible, is it possible to do it without creating a new column and without using a formula, but rather with a keyboard shortcut or a macro or a menu button?

I would find how to do it with myself with a new column + formula, but I want to see if there is another (clever) solution.

Here is a before/after:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill! I am curious if there is a clever idea that can help to avoid creating a new column + using a formula :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```vb
Sub mergeCols()
    Dim separator As String, arr() As Variant
    separator = InputBox("separator: ")
    arr = Selection
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Dim rowString As String
        rowString = vbNullString
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            Dim currentCell As String
            currentCell = arr(i, j)
            If currentCell <> vbNullString Then
                rowString = rowString & currentCell & separator
                arr(i, j) = ""
            End If
        Next j
        If rowString <> vbNullString Then arr(i, LBound(arr, 2)) = Left(rowString, Len(rowString) - Len(separator))
    Next i
    Selection = arr
End Sub
```

Select the area that you want to do this with. **NOT THE COLUMNS**, the specific area and run the macro. It will ask you for a separator so just put in whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should we paste the code? How to make this macro widely available for all Excel files (without manually copy/paste it in each worksheet)?

Comment: @Basj https://trumpexcel.com/personal-macro-workbook/

Comment: Great answer, upvoted, thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you know how to modify it @andrewb, such that if a cell is empty, there is no separator ? Example `hello` `(empty cell)` `world` would give `hello ; world` and not `hello ; ; world`?

Comment: @Basj done. I edited the code in the answer. It should also run faster now as it doesn't loop through cells anymore but copies the selection to an array and works with the array instead.

Comment: Great, thanks @andrewb! Minor problem: when I select 2 or 3 whole columns (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiTHj.png) and call the macro, there is an "error 5", do you know what it is? Same problem if one row is empty: "error 5".

Comment: @Basj yes, you can't select whole columns unfortunately, the macro will crash. There are ways around this but I believe it's safer to just select the area you want to work with.

Comment: Ok @andrewb I won't select whole columns, this makes sense. Another thing: when a row is empty it crashes: example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/296Uh.png

Comment: @Basj Fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: Great work @andrewb!

Answer (score 0):

Additional information to [@andrewb's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1762679/).

1. Menu > Excel Options > Show Developer tab in the ribbon
2. Developer tab > Record a macro > Choose "Personal Macro Workbook", and choose a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>CTRL+M</kbd>
3. Stop recording
4. Click on "Visual Basic" button
5. Click on "VBAProject (PERSONAL.XLSB)" > Modules > Module 1
6. Paste the code from the accepted answer
7. Close Visual Basic and close Excel
8. Accept to "Save to personal workbook"
9. Open an existing Excel file, and test the keyboard shorcut
10. It works!

If then, later, you want to edit the function, you have to:

1. Start Excel
2. Developer tab > Visual Basic > modify the function in PERSONAL.XLSB
3. Developer tab > Macros > Choose the macro > Options...
4. Set up the keyboard shortcut *again* (it seems that the shortcut is removed each time you modify the function)